# How to include addcontentsline on blank page into TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

`\addcontentsline` is written to the toc when the page is "shipped out". If the command is on an empty page which is not written to the pdf or dvi it gets lost.

**Question**: How do I get `\addcontentsline` to work for the empty page below?, *without adding text that's visible*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

blub 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{section 1}
\newpage
%empty page 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{section 2} %lost
\end{document}
```

I'm also interested in the case of sections where there is only a `figure`. In such sections `addcontentsline` does not function. I want a solution where I do not have to put `addcontentsline` *inside* the `figure` for it to work.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding of the question is, that you want `\addcontentsline` on a "virtual" page with new page number, but without having the page in the final document, because it is generated elsewhere.

`\addcontentsline` uses deferred writing `\write` that is actually executed, if the page is shipped out, which contains the write node. However TeX also knows an immediate writing using `\immediate` before `\write`.

The reason for the deferred writing is that the page number is at least known at shipout time in the output routine that usually get called asynchronously at a later time. However in the situation of the question, we are right after a `\newpage` at the top of a new page. Here `\thepage` is known and valid.

The example defines `\NoPageAddContentsLine` that locally redefines `\protected@write`:

- `\immediate\write` is used instead of the deferred `\write`.
- `\protect` must be simplified to `\noexpand`. The original `\protected@write` uses an additional expansion level that is not needed for `\immediate` writing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\NoPageAddContentsLine}[3]{%
  \begingroup
    \newpage
    \let\protected@write\protected@immediate@write
    \addcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \endgroup
  \stepcounter{page}%
}
\newcommand{\protected@immediate@write}[3]{%
  \begingroup
    #2%
    \let\protect\noexpand
    \immediate\write#1{#3}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\bigskip
\hrule
\noindent
blub
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{section 1}
\NoPageAddContentsLine{toc}{section}{section 2}
\NoPageAddContentsLine{lof}{section}{figure 9}
\end{document}
```

**Result:** PDF file with **1** page only and correct page numbers for the virtual pages.

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

To fix the first problem you mention, add something like `\null` to the otherwise-empty page.

To add an "invisible figure" -- whatever that may be... -- to the list of figures, you should use an instruction such as

```
\addcontentsline{lof}{section}{figure 9}
```

and, of course, add a `\listoffigures` instructions to print the list of figures. If the page containing the instruction `\addcontentsline{lof}{section}{figure 9}` is otherwise entirely empty, be sure to provide a `\null` instruction as well...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\bigskip
\hrule
\noindent
blub 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{section 1}
\newpage
\null
%empty page 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{section 2} % no longer lost b/c page no longer completely empty
\newpage
\addcontentsline{lof}{section}{figure 9}
\null
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this creates a whole blank page. Many of my sections *only* have `figure`s and no other thing (see the latter part of my question). If I put `\null` into these sections that only have figures, this will cause the TOC to work again (which is good!) but it will now insert a blank page (which is bad!). Note also that I'm not using 'invisible figures'. My figures are completely normal figures. My problem was that whenever I have a section with only figures and not text, `addcontentsline` no longer functions.

Comment: @user2763361 - I guess I don't understand your setup. If you have a section in your document, don't you have at least a `\section` instruction or something similar? The presence of that command should alleviate the problem of a blank page, right? A different question: How do you create figures that are simultaneously "completely normal" and somehow don't automatically create entries in the List of Figures?

Comment: I'm not having a `list of figures` and haven't even tried to include it. I also don't have a call to `\section`. All I have is `\addcontentsline` - that is, I have a section "show up" in my TOC, but no *real* section in the body of my document.

Comment: ... All I have is (1) A call to `\addcontentsline`, (2) A figure, (3) The next call to `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: @user2763361 - I'm afraid your document's setup still isn't clear to me. Please consider either editing your existing posting or creating a new posting in which you make the issues caused by the setup of your document explicit. Incidentally, if it's mainly the "empty page" issue that's concerning you, could that be solved by leaving out one or more of the `\newpage` instructions?

Answer (score 0):

To add your entry to the toc in every case without adding extra whitespace you could use the following new command:

```
\newcommand{\acl}[3]{
\begingroup
\let\newpage\relax
\null
\addcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}
\endgroup}
```

You can use `\acl` (or any other name you want to give it) just like you would use `\addcontentsline`.

### Explanation of the code:

- `\newcommand` defines the new command (first argument) which takes an amount of arguments specified in its option and does the code in its second argument. Here, the new argument is `\acl` and it takes three arguments, just like `\addcontentsline`!
- `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` enclose the code between them in their little safe heaven.
- `\let\newpage\relax` makes sure LaTeX can't start a new page even if it would want to.
- Because the relaxing is between the groupcommands `\newpage` will work as it should outside the group.